# Buildkite Windows agent cannot find git executable

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables, command-prompt, buildkite

I'm having trouble getting the Windows build agent to run a build. The agent is unable to checkout my source code. (Im using Windows 10) [See GitHub issue](https://github.com/buildkite/agent/issues/487)

I am seeing the following error when running a build:

```
Buildkite Error: There was an error running `git clone -v -- git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git .` (exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%)
```

I have installed `git` using `chocolatey` and `git` is accessible in CMD and Powershell on the agent's host and I can see it in my path if I run `gci env:Path` in Powershell. `git`'s directory is at the end here:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cm...
```

From a build's logs in BK's web UI, I see the following environment variables printed out:

```
BUILDKITE=true
BUILDKITE_AGENT_ACCESS_TOKEN=xxx
BUILDKITE_AGENT_DEBUG=true
BUILDKITE_AGENT_ENDPOINT=https://agent.buildkite.com/v3
BUILDKITE_AGENT_ID=xxx
BUILDKITE_AGENT_NAME=DESKTOP-1
BUILDKITE_AGENT_PID=5180
BUILDKITE_ARTIFACT_PATHS=
BUILDKITE_BIN_PATH=C:\Users\Jason\Downloads\buildkite-agent-windows-amd64-3.0-beta.27
BUILDKITE_BRANCH=fix/build
BUILDKITE_BUILD_CHECKOUT_PATH=builds\DESKTOP-1\myorg\myrepo
BUILDKITE_BUILD_CREATOR=Jason
BUILDKITE_BUILD_CREATOR_EMAIL=myemail@gmail.com
BUILDKITE_BUILD_ID=xxx
BUILDKITE_BUILD_NUMBER=18
BUILDKITE_BUILD_PATH=builds
BUILDKITE_BUILD_URL=https://buildkite.com/myorg/myrepo/builds/18
BUILDKITE_COMMAND=msbuild
BUILDKITE_COMMAND_EVAL=true
BUILDKITE_COMMIT=HEAD
BUILDKITE_GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS=-fxdq
BUILDKITE_GIT_CLONE_FLAGS=-v
BUILDKITE_HOOKS_PATH=hooks
BUILDKITE_JOB_ID=xxx
BUILDKITE_MESSAGE=First build
BUILDKITE_ORGANIZATION_SLUG=myorg
BUILDKITE_PIPELINE_DEFAULT_BRANCH=master
BUILDKITE_PIPELINE_PROVIDER=github
BUILDKITE_PIPELINE_SLUG=myrepo
BUILDKITE_PLUGINS_PATH=plugins
BUILDKITE_PROJECT_PROVIDER=github
BUILDKITE_PROJECT_SLUG=myorg/myrepo
BUILDKITE_PULL_REQUEST=false
BUILDKITE_PULL_REQUEST_REPO=
BUILDKITE_REPO=git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git
BUILDKITE_REPO_SSH_HOST=github.com
BUILDKITE_RETRY_COUNT=0
BUILDKITE_SCRIPT_PATH=msbuild
BUILDKITE_SOURCE=ui
BUILDKITE_SSH_FINGERPRINT_VERIFICATION=true
BUILDKITE_TAG=
BUILDKITE_TIMEOUT=false
CI=true
PATH=C:\Users\Jason\Downloads\buildkite-agent-windows-amd64-3.0-beta.27;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
```

Note that `PATH` in that output is not the same as my `PATH` from the Powershell and does not include the path to gits binary.

Full build output:

```
Build environment variables 0s
BUILDKITE=true
BUILDKITE_AGENT_ACCESS_TOKEN=xxx
BUILDKITE_AGENT_DEBUG=true
BUILDKITE_AGENT_ENDPOINT=https://agent.buildkite.com/v3
BUILDKITE_AGENT_ID=xxx
BUILDKITE_AGENT_NAME=DESKTOP-1
BUILDKITE_AGENT_PID=5180
BUILDKITE_ARTIFACT_PATHS=
BUILDKITE_BIN_PATH=C:\Users\Jason\Downloads\buildkite-agent-windows-amd64-3.0-beta.27
BUILDKITE_BRANCH=fix/build
BUILDKITE_BUILD_CHECKOUT_PATH=builds\DESKTOP-1\myorg\myrepo
BUILDKITE_BUILD_CREATOR=Jason
BUILDKITE_BUILD_CREATOR_EMAIL= myemail@gmail.com
BUILDKITE_BUILD_ID=xxx
BUILDKITE_BUILD_NUMBER=18
BUILDKITE_BUILD_PATH=builds
BUILDKITE_BUILD_URL=https://buildkite.com/myorg/myrepo/builds/18
BUILDKITE_COMMAND=msbuild
BUILDKITE_COMMAND_EVAL=true
BUILDKITE_COMMIT=HEAD
BUILDKITE_GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS=-fxdq
BUILDKITE_GIT_CLONE_FLAGS=-v
BUILDKITE_HOOKS_PATH=hooks
BUILDKITE_JOB_ID=xxx
BUILDKITE_MESSAGE=First build
BUILDKITE_ORGANIZATION_SLUG=myorg
BUILDKITE_PIPELINE_DEFAULT_BRANCH=master
BUILDKITE_PIPELINE_PROVIDER=github
BUILDKITE_PIPELINE_SLUG=myrepo
BUILDKITE_PLUGINS_PATH=plugins
BUILDKITE_PROJECT_PROVIDER=github
BUILDKITE_PROJECT_SLUG=myorg/myrepo
BUILDKITE_PULL_REQUEST=false
BUILDKITE_PULL_REQUEST_REPO=
BUILDKITE_REPO=git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git
BUILDKITE_REPO_SSH_HOST=github.com
BUILDKITE_RETRY_COUNT=0
BUILDKITE_SCRIPT_PATH=msbuild
BUILDKITE_SOURCE=ui
BUILDKITE_SSH_FINGERPRINT_VERIFICATION=true
BUILDKITE_TAG=
BUILDKITE_TIMEOUT=false
CI=true
PATH=C:\Users\Jason\Downloads\buildkite-agent-windows-amd64-3.0-beta.27;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
Running global environment hook 0s
# Skipping, no hook script found at "hooks\environment.bat"
Running global pre-checkout hook    0s
# Skipping, no hook script found at "hooks\pre-checkout.bat"
Preparing build directory   0s
# Changing working directory to "builds\DESKTOP-1\myorg\myrepo"
⚠ Buildkite Warning: Could not performn `ssh-keygen` (exec: "ssh-keygen": executable file not found in %PATH%)
> git clone -v -- git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git .
 Buildkite Error: There was an error running `git clone -v -- git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.git .` (exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command 'git.clone' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58422951/command-git-clone-not-found)

Answer (score 1):

Your build output doesn't seem to have those chocolatey paths:

```
PATH=C:\Users\Jason\Downloads\buildkite-agent-windows-amd64-3.0-beta.27;
```

You might need to add an [agent environment hook](https://buildkite.com/docs/agent/hooks) which adds the right directories to the path. Or try updating to the latest beta which might fix the issue.