# Command 'git.clone' not found

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-clone

I've setup a Windows 10 machine with VSCode and needed to clone a repo so I installed the tooling (Git, NuGet, posh-git and the Environment Variable) using Powershell:

```
iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
choco install git -y

#devlog('Install NuGet, Git, SSH Keys directory and set region')
$newPath = "$($env:PATH)C:\Program Files\Git\bin;"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( 'PATH', $newPath, "Machine")
$env:PATH = $newPath
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
install-module posh-git -force
```

Now in VSCode when I try a Git Clone I get an error:

> Command 'git.clone' not found

I have **git** installed as per the Powershell code.  I have typed `git clone` with the space not the dot and same problem.

Also I should note this code worked perfectly about a month ago, so what could the problem be?

Comment: did you try running `git` only

Comment: I had to trust current workspace or folder. Git extension is disabled until then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Git install has changed slightly. In the above code I set the Environment variable for the Git\Bin folder:

```
 Directory of C:\Program Files\Git\bin

10/16/2019  10:34 PM    <DIR>          .
10/16/2019  10:34 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/17/2019  09:27 AM            43,616 bash.exe
08/17/2019  09:27 AM            43,096 git.exe
08/17/2019  09:27 AM            43,616 sh.exe
```

That's not where VSCode likes to find the exe. Adding a Environment Variable to **C:\Program Files\Git\cmd** and not *C:\Program Files\Git\bin* resolves the problem:

[image]

```
Directory of C:\Program Files\Git\cmd

10/16/2019  10:34 PM    <DIR>          .
10/16/2019  10:34 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/17/2019  09:27 AM           151,136 git-gui.exe
08/17/2019  09:27 AM            43,096 git-lfs.exe
08/17/2019  09:27 AM            43,096 git.exe
08/17/2019  09:27 AM           151,128 gitk.exe
08/17/2019  09:27 AM             3,022 start-ssh-agent.cmd
08/17/2019  09:27 AM             2,723 start-ssh-pageant.cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ton of VSCode extensions relating to Git, uninstall them, restart VSCode and try to clone a repo again. Did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are in **Restricted Mode**.

In **Restricted Mode**, **Git** built-in extension is disabled.

[image: Git extension disabled]

Press [**️ Restricted Mode**] on the bottom left corner of VS Code window.

[image: Where to look]

From the **Workspace Trust** tab that opens, you can choose to trust the current folder or the parent folder.

Learn more about the Workspace Trust here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspace-trust

Answer (score 0):

Change 'Restricted Mode'   to trust .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).